# mysql блокировки в репликации

Tags: mysql, транзакции

**Что есть**

- mysql c 1 master node + 2 slaves (только на чтение)
- дефолтный транзакционный уровень тоесть REPEATABLE READ

**Вопрос**

- При REPEATABLE READ мы не должны видить значение таблицы которые в данный момет обновляються, другими словами слейвы не должны иметь возможность читать заблокированные записи в мастере. Но в документацих находил только информацию что пока транзакция незакомичена данные не передадуться по слейвам. Как тогда поддерживаеться уровень изоляции REPEATABLE READ?
- Работают ли блокировки в реплике также как без нее?

**Примечание к ответу**

- кроме ссылки на мануал было бы хорошо услишать твое обьяснение

Answer (score 0):

> При REPEATABLE READ мы не должны видить значение таблицы которые в данный момет обновляються, другими словами слейвы не должны иметь возможность читать заблокированные записи в мастере.

Нет. Вы неправильно понимаете что такое и как работает REPEATABLE READ.

При этом уровне изоляции все немодифицирующие запросы в транзакции возвращают данные какими они были в БД в момент начала транзакции. Т.е. все запросы видят слепок (snapshot) БД  на момнет начала транзации. Записи при этом могут быть модифицированны другими транзакциями, но текущая этих модификаций не видит. Так что проблем у реплик с реализацией уровня изоляции REPEATABLE READ нет.

Вот цитата из документации:

> Consistent read is the default mode in which InnoDB processes SELECT statements in READ COMMITTED and REPEATABLE READ isolation levels. A consistent read does not set any locks on the tables it accesses, and therefore other sessions are free to modify those tables at the same time a consistent read is being performed on the table.

Что касается блокировок в реплике. Реплика ничем не отличается в это плане от мастера, кроме того, что если ее модифицировать, то этим можно сломать репликацию, т.к. новые изменения пришедшие с мастера будут конфликтовать с изменениями сделанными локально.

Так что блокировать записи в реплике можно, но это будет блокировка в этом конкретном экземпляре БД и конфликтовать такая блокировка будет только с другими попытками захватить блокировку именно на этой же реплике. То есть конфликта с блокировкой сделаной на мастере не будет.